# How to handle the following cases in a friend request data model?

Tags: mysql, database, datamodel

For a project that I am on, on of the requirements is users being able to send each other friend requests and either accepting them or declining them.

Side note: the project is built on Laravel.

At first my data model for those friendships was as such (leaving out things as timestamps etc. in this example):

```
pivot_friend_request
====================
sender_id
receiver_id
status
```

Of course `sender_id` and `receiver_id` have a foreign key constraint to `id` on the user table.

Here I ran into this case issue:

**CASE:**

1. User `foo` invites `bar` (table row: foo-bar-pending)
2. Meanwhile user `bar` never reads his notifications but searches user `foo`
3. User `bar` invites user `foo` (table row: bar-foo-pending)
4. Now I have two table rows for those two users that have sent friend requests to each other that are both pending.

What is the best way to check if foo-bar is already present before also inserting bar-foo (regardless of the request status)?

Then I asked my project manager what do to, resulting in him asking me why I was going about it like this. To have a more object oriented approach he told me to have separate tables for the requests and actual friendships because a request is a request and a friendship is a friendship.

I think he made a good point there but it confused me even more. Because:

1. Now I have to deal with the above mentioned case twice and I still don't have a solution to it.
2. Plus it made me think on how to handle the request table. Should the request be removed from it after accepting or should there still be a status of the request?
3. Can it be more efficient like this because I now see it like this:

   - Request is sent by `bar`
   - Check if `foo`-`bar` already exists in request table
   - If exists update `pending` to `accepted` else create new one with `pending`. (If already accepted return 'Already friends message')
   - Create new row in friendship table

Also... what if a friendship gets removed? I know have two tables where I should update that status? The request and the actual friendship table?

I really really need some pointers here it seems.

Answer (score 1):

if friendship get removed you have to update both request and friendship table. for example,

1. `bar` invites `foo`.then in `request` table you can set `status`as pending
2. once `foo` accepts the friend request add row to a `friends` table.
3. later `foo` unfriends `bar`. then friend table will be updated.
4. now `bar` wants to invite `foo` again. but`bar` cannot send a new friend request to `foo` since there is already a record in the `request` table. so you have to update `request` table at the 3rd step or 2nd step.

however this whole scenario depends on your requirements.

Comment: alright... and how to best go about checking for the existance of `foo`-`bar` in the request table if `bar` invites `foo`? So I don't end up with both `foo`-`bar` and `bar`-`foo` there?

Comment: check if  `foo-bar` exists in the request table with status `pending` before `bar` invite `foo`. if it does never let `bar` invite `foo`